# Unknown screen output of manually installed Python 2.7

Tags: python

I installed Python 2.7 today using:

```
./configure --prefix=/home/zhanwu/local --enable-shared --enable-profiling --with-pydebug
make install
```

Then I keep getting something like "[37745 refs]" on screen after each function call:

```
[zhanwu@cluster ~]$ ~/local/bin/python
Python 2.7.1 (r271:86832, Jun 16 2011, 17:45:05) 
[GCC 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-44)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sys
[37745 refs]
>>> print 'test'
test
[37745 refs]
>>> sys.exit()
[18048 refs]
[zhanwu@cluster ~]$
```

What does those numbers mean? Anything wrong here and can I get rid of them?

uname -a result:

```
[zhanwu@cluster ~]$ uname -a
Linux cluster.xxx.xxx.xxx 2.6.18-128.1.14.el5 #1 SMP Wed Jun 17 06:38:05 EDT 2009 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: I'd guess it's either `--enable-profiling` or `--with-pydebug ` that's creating the extra output.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You get these because you configured the build with `--with-pydebug`.  They denote the number of references Python is currently keeping track of.  To get rid of them, configure without `--with-pydebug`.

Comment: redo "configure" and "make", anyway to turn it off without reinstalling it?

Comment: You need to recompile the interpreter -- I don't think there is another way.