# how to stop python3 prints reference count after each command

Tags: python, python-3.x

After each command python prints refs count. I want to stop printing reference count, how can I do that?

Example:

```
>>> s = 'Hello World'
[786699 refs]
>>> str(s)
'Hello World'
[786699 refs]
>>>
```

Comment: Restart your python interpreter? Standard Python installations do not do this.

Comment: yes, never seen this behaviour...

Comment: That looks like what you'd get if you built Python in debug mode.  Did you compile it from source yourself?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not standard behavior:

```
$ python
Python 3.3.2 (default, May 21 2013, 11:50:47) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple Clang 4.1 ((tags/Apple/clang-421.11.66))] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
Running with pythonstartup.py
>>> s = 'Hello World'
>>> str(s)
'Hello World'
>>>
```

You may get this because you configured the build with `--with-pydebug`, as described in [this post.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6375120/unknown-screen-output-of-manually-installed-python-2-7)

Comment: Thanks! I re-installed python without --with-pydebug option and it worked.