# Turn off python reference counting output

Tags: python

So, whenever I do anything in Python, I keep getting this refs count output. For example:

```
xxxxx@li282-82:~$ python
Python 2.7.3 (default, Feb 28 2013, 20:42:30) 
[GCC 4.6.3] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import django
[40347 refs]
>>> django.VERSION
(1, 5, 2, 'final', 0)
[40349 refs]
>>> 
[40349 refs]
[19961 refs]
xxxxx@li282-82:~$ logout
```

How do I turn that off?!

Comment: Do you have anything set to run at interpreter startup that might be enabling GC debug flags?

Comment: Did you compile Python with some debugging flags turned on? (*Just a guess*).

Comment: Try running: ``Python -S``

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6375120/unknown-screen-output-of-manually-installed-python-2-7

Comment: @alecxe, thanks. Can I just install Python again from source? I've always thought doing a `sudo apt-get install` is better than compiling from source for maintenance...

Answer (score 3):

It looks to me like your interpretter was compiled with a [debug flag](http://docs.python.org/devguide/setup.html#unix).  To get rid of it, I *think* you'll need to recompile.

Comment: I think I'm just using the default Python installation. Might have upgraded it. Python path is `/usr/local/bin/python`; how do I recompile?

Comment: ``/usr/local/bin/python`` smells of Python compiled from source. See: http://docs.python.org/2/using/unix.html#building-python

Comment: @JamesMills Will recompiling it break the current packages? Should I link some libraries again? In particular, I'm worried about my MySQL installation and other stuff. This is a live website and I don't want any downtime.

Comment: There won't be many things depending on the libraries installed to ``/usr/local/lib`` and certainly not many dependent on the Python libraires (*.so files*) -- Unless you have applications that are written in C/C++ embedded Python. What you **should check** is what other apps/tools/web-apps live on your site are currently using ``/usr/local/bin/python``. Use ``lsof`` for example.

Comment: @JamesMills -- but will already installed 3rd party modules be preserved?  If it's really critical, I might put a fresh install somewhere else, test the site against that fresh install before pushing to production...

Comment: You can always change the installation prefix with ``--prefix=/path/to/install``

Answer (score 3):

From `Misc/SpecialBuilds.txt`:

> Py_REF_DEBUG
>
> ---
>
> Turn on aggregate reference counting.  This arranges that extern _Py_RefTotal
>   hold a count of all references, the sum of ob_refcnt across all objects.  In a
>   debug-mode build, this is where the "8288" comes from in

```
>>> 23
23
[8288 refs]
>>>
```

> Note that if this count increases when you're not storing away new objects,
>   there's probably a leak.  Remember, though, that in interactive mode the special
>   name "_" holds a reference to the last result displayed!
>
> Py_REF_DEBUG also checks after every decref to verify that the refcount hasn't
>   gone negative, and causes an immediate fatal error if it has.
>
> Special gimmicks:

```
    sys.gettotalrefcount()
    Return current total of all refcounts.
```

`Py_REF_DEBUG` is also *implied* by some other debugging options.  But everyone is right:  *somehow* or other you have a debug build of Python.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @mgilson you likely have a source-compiled Python installed (*hinted by `/usr/local/bin/python`*). If you want to rebuild Python from source, go download the latest source code of the version you're after and follow these *rough* instructions:

```
tar jxvf Python-x.y.z.tar.bz2
cd Python-x.y.z
./configure --prefix=/usr/local \
            --mandir=/usr/local/man \
            --enable-shared \
            --with-threads \
            --enable-ipv6 \
            --with-dbmliborder=gdbm
make
make install
```

See: http://docs.python.org/2/using/unix.html#building-python